# Dynamic commas in author list

Tags: dynamic, list

I would like to have dynamic commas in a list of authors, so for example if there is only one author of an article it would show: AUTHOR.

However if there was two or more authors, I would like to show a comma or an and bewteen each name like: AUTHOR ONE and AUTHOR TWO. Or in the example four authors: AUTHOR ONE, AUTHOR TWO, AUTHOR THREE and AUTHOR FOUR.

Note the 'and' and ',' in each example.

The code I'm using pulls out the correct data, but I need to put in dynamic commas depending how many authors each article has.

Code:

```
<h6 class="entry-meta">by {pp_author_one} {if pp_author_two != ""}, {pp_author_two}{/if} {if pp_author_three != ""}, {pp_author_three}{/if} {if pp_author_four != ""}and {pp_author_four}{/if} | <time datetime="{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i"}" pubdate>{date_heading}{entry_date format="%d %F %Y"}{/date_heading}</time></h6><hr>
```

Comment: Mmm, that is bit tricky. I am not giving you a solution but pointing you a direction. https://github.com/danott/ee-loopee

Comment: can you please mention that how you are pulling the authors. It would be easy for someone to answer.

Comment: What type of field are the authors stored in?

Comment: @DimitriKouvdis Thanks. I have now installed this and will play. :)

Comment: @JeremyGimbel The field type is Text Input from a single entry channel. There are four Text Input fields, one for each author.

Comment: @BhashkarYadav Yes, will do. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: Another option might me to use Matrix instead. Then you'll have a tag that loops through the rows and can insert a comma or "and" conditionally.

Comment: or you can use List FT from http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/field-pack

Comment: I think that I would enable php in this template en out all authors in a array. Count the number of items in the array and echo this. Because you know how big your array is, you know where to place a 'comma' and a 'and'.

Comment: This is exactly that I'm trying to figured out and this question is from 2014 with no solution...
EE sucks! With PHP I can do that in 2 minutes...

Comment: This is not a helpful comment. The 2014 question is not the same as the one you have asked (and which has been answered).  If you are a skilled php programmer maybe you should consider reading up on EE's add-on system - which allows you to securely and conveniently interact with EE data using php from within the EE CMS itself.